# how to change array structure from laravel collection?

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

im newb using laravel and hope someone helps me.

i have data details from database and get it with laravel collection ,here my code :

```
 public function index()
  {
    $corpus = V_Corpus::select('details')->pluck('details');

    dd($corpus);
  }
```

and the result var_dump is an array with structure like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#205 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
   0 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
   1 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
   2 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
  ]
}
```

the problem is how can u change the array srtructure from the previous array to look like this :

```
array:3 [▼
   0 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
   1 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
   2 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
]
```

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it, just add toArray().

```
$corpus = V_Corpus::select('details')->pluck('details')->toArray();

dd($corpus);
```

the output look like this :

```
array:3 [▼
   0 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
   1 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
   2 => "CPU Socket LGA1151 Chipset Intel Z390  4 x DIMM Max 64GB DDR4"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get all the result always as array by changing

config/database.php

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
```

to

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
```

Or modify the index function

```
public function index() {
    $corpus = V_Corpus::select('details')->pluck('details')->toArray();

    dd($corpus);
}
```

Hope this will help.